# "Pixels" Missing as an Option for Image Size (Re-sizing) in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, cs5, pixel

I recently updated to Photoshop CS5 and I noticed that "Pixels" is not an option to re-size to. I only see percent, inches, cm, mm, points and picas. I have also made sure that I have set all of my units to pixels in "my preferences". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Image Size options]

In the Image Size option menu, you will not have pixel as a unit in the "Document Size" pane. But the pane above it, "Pixel Dimensions" you have a choice of using px or % as units.

Comment: In other words: think `Document Size` as the physical, *print* size and `Pixel Dimensions` as its digital representation on the screen. Moreover, if one designs for the screen, `Document Size` shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Nope. This is not true. When I try to change image size, I do not have the option to change the pixel amount. Pixel dimensions are set and cannot be changed.

Comment: Kelley, in newer versions of Photoshop, if `Resample` is **un**checked then pixels will not be available. You have to check `Resample` in order to use pixels.